# Can't pass a parameter to $_POST using the XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm practicing PHP and the use of the XMLHttpRequest object. I'm trying to make a function that checks whether a username is already taken or not.

This is my javascript function:

```
function checkUser(username) {
if (username.length < 8) return 2;

request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("POST", "checkUser.php?t=" + Math.random(), true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded');
params = 'nameToBeChecked=' + username; 

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        if(request.responseText == "true") {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (request.responseText == "false") {
            return 0;
        }
        else console.log("ERROR: " + request.responseText);
    }
}
request.send(params);
}
```

This is my PHP file:

```
require 'userActions.php';

if(isset($_POST['nameToBeChecked'])) {
    if(fetch_userid($_POST['nameToBeChecked']) == null) echo "true";
    else echo "false";
}
echo !isset($_POST['nameToBeChecked']) ? "Field doesn't exist" : "Field exists" ;
```

The last line on my PHP file is there for debugging purposes. I discovered that when I send a POST request to my PHP file, the field nameToBeChecked isn't created in the PHP file. I can't find what the problem is online. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again after you change this line:

```
/* request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded'); */
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

as defined here: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` [from https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept the answer if this helped you :)

Comment: I did, I also wanted to upvote, unfortunately, my account is still too new :(